# How to bind change event dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am doing username availability check. I made jquery ajax call, its working fine and if username already in use i want to make label and textbox in red color. for this purpose i am adding css class in the callback function of `$Post()` method. The problem I have is css is not applying. I think the problem is in dynamically binding the event So please can any one help me in this. Here is my jquery script,

```
$(document).on('change', '#uName', function() {

    var uName = $(this).val();//get the string typed by user
    if (uName!=''){
        $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/UserNameCheckController',{'uName':uName},
               function(data) {
                   $('.status').html(data);
                   var status = $.trim($("#status").text());
                   if(status=="Username in use try another"){
                       $('#unameBlock').addClass('error'); 
                   }
               });
    }
    else{
        $('.status').html('');
    }
});
```

Help me to fix this please. Thanks.

Comment: You are using #unameBlock maybe an case error ? (uNameBlock)

Comment: You can tell if the binding is working by putting an `alert()` in the handler, or by setting a breakpoint in the Javascript debugger.

Comment: yes `alert()` is working, I put it just before `if()`

Comment: @Tony What should I change `#unameBlock` is a id of `<div>` tag.

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes inside if also its working

Comment: Css selectors are case sensitive, maybe you should replace $("#unameBlock") by $("#uNameBlock") . if not, could you post the code with the div ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error lies on your class selector

Change

```
$.trim($("#status").text());
```

to

```
$.trim($(".status").text());
//--------^-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to

```
var status = $.trim($("#status").html());
```

it could be .status or #status depends upon the class or id you have used in your html.